# Docker - send http request from one container to another

Tags: reactjs, docker

I cannot send an HTTP request to backend container when I'm running app on AWS server production. However, when I'm running app locally I can make requests to backend just fine. For making requests I use fetch:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/something')
```

Here is how project structure looks like:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
|
├── backend
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── server.js
|
└── frontend
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── package.json
    ├── public
    │   └── index.html
    └── src
       ├── components
       ├── data
       ├── index.js
       ├── routes.js
       ├── static
       ├── tests
       └── views
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: frontend/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/frontend
    ports:
      - "80:5000"
    links:
      - backend
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Dockerfile in frontend:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /frontend

WORKDIR /frontend

ADD . /frontend

VOLUME ["/frontend"]

EXPOSE 5000

CMD yarn && yarn build && yarn global add serve && serve -s build
```

Dockerfile in backend:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /backend

WORKDIR /backend

ADD . /backend

VOLUME ["/backend"]

EXPOSE 8000

CMD yarn && yarn start
```

Can someone explain me what is wrong with my config? I'm very confused, because it works without any issues locally.

Comment: Can you add some details about how you're deploying these containers? All on one EC2 instance? In Swarm on EC2? On ECS? Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to all deployment stuff. Yes, I'm running all on one EC2 instance - ubuntu 16.04. Instance type is t2.micro. I'm deploying it by clonning repo, and then running docker-compose build and docker-compose up.

Comment: Where is the error saying your request is failing? Is it just a case of timing? (one container taking longer to come up) ?

Comment: In console in chrome devtools it is saying "Failed to fetch". Frontend is on localhost, and backend on localhost:8000. When I'm locally making request to localhost:8000 from frontend it works OK. But on EC2 it is failing with the above error. The problem is that on EC2 it wants to make request to localhost:8000 on my computer instead of that on EC2. I checked that by making fake server.

Answer (score 11):

**TLDR: Need to change the frontend code to call the current host instead of 'localhost'**

The problem is your app is saying 'hey localhost' instead of 'hey VPS ip', when visiting from YOUR browser. You need to edit your frontend code to visit the current host you're visiting. That's why you're receiving a request on YOUR localhost server.

Instead of `fetch("http:///localhost:8000/something")` change it to `fetch("http://"+location.host+":8000")` (There are better ways, this gets it done).

Also note docker containers are a little different in terms of networking as well. A docker container doesn't really have a concept of 'localhost' the same way non docker container apps do. You have to use the VPS's IP/Local IP when making the call from server to server. A trick I use is to use docker's default docker0 bridge 172.17.0.1.

I tend to use networks over 'links' and actually cant comment fully on it, but when containers were on the same docker network, you could access the other container by using the container's name. This only works for server side code however, ie: node.js server -> node.js server/mongo db. Example mongodb connection would be `mongodb://mongo_server:27017/mydatabase` and mongo_server would resolve to the container's IP.

Another thing you'll possibly encounter when attempting to use the IP is your firewall, you would have to allow that particular ip/port in through your firewall as well.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! Really explained many things for me - thank you again! However now, when I do `fetch("http://"+location.host+":8000")`  the request is pending. I also checked it by doing `curl http://some_ip:8000` on EC2 and it remains "waiting". And when I do `curl http://localhost:8000` it works without any issues.

Comment: On EC2 itself, it understands what 'localhost' is, thus `curl localhost:8000` will work. The browser in which you are visiting will visit YOUR 'localhost', if you shut your server down, it wouldn't work. Another problem could be some built-in functionality with EC2. On digital ocean, there's no built-in firewall and you can expose any port you want, however on Azure, you need to add explicit 'end points' in their GUI to allow connections into those ports. Ive never used EC2 so I cant comment on that.

Comment: You are totally right! Thanks. I added port 8000 to my Inbound Rules as Custom TCP Rule and everything seems to work just great. Thank you a lot!

Comment: OMG, thank you, you saved my day, I'm looking for an answer the second day. The correct answer is 172.17.0.1, not localhost :)